# MFC Radio button freezes entire screen

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, mfc, radio-button

I'm a bit at a loss here.  Simply put, i created 2 radio buttons on my MFC GUI (vs2010) via the toolbox.  I put each of them as a group so i could use the wizard to create a member variable for them.  At this point, i run the code to test functionality.  I don't expect much to happen since i don't have any handling code for the clicks, but what does happen is my entire screen freezes.  So i click on either of the radio buttons, it shows that it is checked, but after that, i cannot click anything else on the screen. It has basically become frozen until i restart the program. 
Has anyone seen this before?

.h file entry:

```
CButton testRadio;
CButton testRadio1;
```

.cpp file entry

```
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TEST_RADIO, testRadio);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TESTRADIO1, testRadio1);
```

i know that the control ID's are not repeated, so that is not an issue.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what sort of concept a single-radio-button group is supposed to model.

Comment: what it is supposed to model is irrelevant.  When i create the handlers, i can force the check manually.  Regardless how i group the radio buttons, the entire screen freezes.

Comment: Radio buttons offer mutually exclusive options. Providing a single mutually exclusive option is not offering an option at all. At any rate, the code you posted is insufficient. Provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that exhibits the described behavior. And include the resource script.

Comment: I'd love to be able to recreate it in a test program, but i can't.  Even doing the exact same steps, i cannot get the screen to freeze like i can in my in my original.

If i control what is clicked and what is not clicked, then i am manually providing the mutual exclusion myself and not relying on the system to do it.

Comment: I believe this is what i am looking for....

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261192

If a button with the BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON style is clicked and is followed in the tab order by a child dialog box, it enters an endless loop.